# Table expand row with just CSS

Tags: css, html-table

I have some markup like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>  

    <tbody>
        <tr class="main">
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content2</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="more">
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="more-link"><a tabindex="0" href="#">Show more info</a></div>
                <div class="more-info">
                    more info goes here
                </div>
            </td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And some CSS:

```
td, th{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.main td{
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.main td{
 border-bottom: 0;   
}

.more td{
    border-top: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.more-link{
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}

.more-link:focus + div, .more-link:active + div{
    height: auto;
}
```

What I want to do is that when the "show more info" link is clicked, the table row called "more" expands.

The problems:

- There is no effect if I set the `td` inside `more` to have a height of 0;
- If I set height of the `more-info` div to `0`, or `display:none`, the table row still takes up space.

I would like to do this with just CSS, javascript can be used to make it better, but the basics should just work without javascript.

How can I get my `more` row to expand when the `show more info` link is clicked?

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QJr2e/

Comment: you can't catch a click with just css but you can catch a mouse hover with css. and you can use `height`,`overflow:hidden` with `:hover` css pseudo class and expand the row on mouse over.

Comment: He is correct.. css wont pickup on a click event.. But mouse hover is a css event and you can build off that...

Comment: I tried setting `overflow:hidden` and `height`, but that just removed the `show more info` link and did nothing to change the height. And no, we can use `:focus` and `:active` to capture "clicks" with just css like so: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-click-flyout.html#url

Comment: @tpaksu You can't capture a click event, but you can capture a target. (`:target`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Instead of using `position:relative` to move the "show more info" link, I gave it a `float:left`. This allowed me to move it anywhere I want using `margin`, while reorganizing the flow.

Instead of using `height`, I just set `more-info` to `display:none`, and then when the "show more info" link is clicked:

```
.more-link:active + div, .more-link:focus + div{
    display: block;
}
```